# limit of the sequence $a_n = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+...}}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, nested-radicals

I have already shown that the sequence is monotone and bounded, so it is convergent. what I need is to calculate the limit when $a_n = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+...}}}}$, $n \rightarrow \infty$, unnder the condition "do not use polynomials of degree 4" to calculate said limit. I don't know the reason why the teacher put that condition

Comment: **Hint :** $$(a_n^2-2)^2-3=a_n$$

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's a polynomial of degree $4$.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist No, this is an equality.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe A distinction without a difference, IMO.

Comment: I'm very curious how the teacher expects this solved without a quartic.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Presumably that should be 
$$
(a_{n+1}^2 - 2)^2 - 3 = a_n
$$

Comment: It is also interesting to know the meaning of the verb "calculate".

Comment: It is completely unclear what the O.P. means by "..." in the expression for a_n. Possibly the teacher wanted students to solve the problem without using the **formula** for the roots of a quartic polynomial. It's probably best to ask the teacher for clarification.

Comment: @user What do you want to know about the meaning of "calculate" here?

Comment: The exact forms of the solution here are awful.  I would ask for a clarification.

Comment: The solution is given by the system $a^2=2+b$, $b^2=3+a$ (the value of $a$). This only has degree $2$ polynomials, although solving it requires degree $4$ polynomials. Maybe the teacher meant something like that... idk.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist For example how  the result of the calculation should be presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the only way I can think of to get a solution that doesn't involve polynomials of degree $4$.

The following system of equations gives the solution of the problem: $\left\{\begin{matrix}a^2=2+b\\b^2=3+a\end{matrix}\right. $, in particular, the solution to $a$ would give the desired result. This is because $a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2+\cdots}}}$ and $b=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\cdots}}}$ Therefore, $a=\sqrt{2+b}$ and $b=\sqrt{3+a}$.  And it is possible to solve that system numerically, by Newton's method, for example (numerical methods for this type of problems are usual, because many times the analytical solutions are horrendous).

Answer (score 5):

This does not answer the question but is here to show the connection to quartic polynomials for the OP.  I'm guessing there is some work around to not have to solve the quartic.

---

Let $a=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$ denote the number in question, namely,
$$
a = \sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+...}}}}
$$
The "trick" in these types of problems (as pointed out in the comments) is to notice that the right hand side can also be written in terms of $a$ yielding
$$
a=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3+a}}.
$$
With some simple algebraic manipulations this result can be recast as the quartic equation
$$
a^4-4a^2-a+1=0.
$$
This quartic has four real roots. To determine which root we want we note that $a>\sqrt 2=1.41\dots$, which leaves us with only root that fits these criteria
$$
a=\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}
   \left(8+\frac{28}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(187+3 i
   \sqrt{5871}\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(187+3 i
   \sqrt{5871}\right)}\right)}+\frac{1}{2}
   \sqrt{\frac{16}{3}-\frac{28}{3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2}
   \left(187+3 i \sqrt{5871}\right)}}-\frac{1}{3}
   \sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(187+3 i
   \sqrt{5871}\right)}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{\frac{1}{3}
   \left(8+\frac{28}{\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(187+3 i
   \sqrt{5871}\right)}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{2} \left(187+3 i
   \sqrt{5871}\right)}\right)}}}=2.061\dots
$$

Comment: Out of curiosity, I put that polynomial into Sage, and it appears the Galois group of the polynomial's splitting field is all of $S_4$.  Given that, there probably isn't any nicer expression for the roots.

Comment: @DanielSchepler Interesting.  I was wondering if there was a way to simplify this expression.